# Which car is this?

Tags: old-cars

Can anybody help me to identify the year, make and model of this car?

[image]

Comment: Bloody lovely cars :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Rover P5, see the [Rover P5 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rover_P5) for further pictures.

Comment: Good find XTaran. I looked earlier and narrowed it down to European 60s model vehicle, but didn't get farther than that. This *appears* to be a Mark III Coupé from the pictures on Wikipedia and description given there. The mirrors being back on the door is throwing me off, though.

Comment: The mirrors are probably an after-market thing. Cars that old may have had them on the wings originally, but in the 70's they started putting them on the doors instead. If old car wingd ahev been replaced (likely by this time), usually the holes aren't cut for wing mirrors so temptation is to put them on the doors. They're more useful on the doors anyway :-)